# I want to GROUPBY in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have two column `Code` and `Score`. Like this

```
| Code | Score |
|:----:|:-----:|
| M01  | 4     |
| M05  | 3     |
| M02  | 4     |
| M01  | 5     |
| M04  | 4     |
| M01  | 3     |
```

I want to get the **AVERAGE** of each `score` with their respective `Code`.

Something like this OUTPUT:

```
| Code | Average |
|:----:|:-------:|
| M01  | 4       |
| M05  | 3       |
| M02  | 4       |
| M04  | 4       |
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: a pivot table will do this for you

Comment: Hey @PeterH, I want to get the `COUNTIFS` of Score which is >= 4 for each Code.

Comment: No problems, use SUMIFS/COUNTIFS.

Comment: But How do I use `COUNTIFS` When I want to COUNT the Range: `Score` whose values are Criteria: >=4. And comes under each category of Code.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar that is not mentioned in your question

Comment: @PeterH that was my mistake. Can you help me out here?

Comment: Hi @MaqsudInamdar create a new question detailing as much as you can what you need, show some before and after examples

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is in column A2:B7 of Sheet1, and the output is in Sheet2. In B2 of sheet2 (beside M01), put :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7=Sheet2!A2))/COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,Sheet2!A2)
```

idea : using `(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7=Sheet2!A2)` to 'generate' a list of 0 & 1, then multiply by the score list, then divide by the number of times the M01 occurred in the defined list.

Please share if it works/not. ( :